# RabbitMqBundle consumer exiting with exception "Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 1 byte" and "Broken pipe or closed connection"

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

Previously asked questions with same exception message did not solve my problem.

I have a consumer that is called from the command line, using the standard bundle cli command:

```
app/console rabbitmq:consumer -m 120 myproject_download
```

After consuming a few messages and performing the task as it should, it exits with the following exception:

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException]
Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 1 bytes

rabbitmq:consumer [-m|--messages [MESSAGES]] [-r|--route [ROUTE]] [-l|--memory-limit [MEMORY-LIMIT]] [-d|--debug] [-w|--without-signals] [--] <name>

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException' with message 'Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes' in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:161
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(147): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read(7)
#1 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(105): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(528): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(568): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(0)
#4 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(214): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(1, 0)
#5 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Chan in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 161

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException' with message 'Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes' in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:161
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(147): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read(7)
#1 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(105): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(528): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(568): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(0)
#4 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(214): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(1, 0)
#5 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Chan in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 161
```

Inside the consumer I also send a message to a new queue. Using the standard Symfony dependency injection. If I leave out sending this message, the following exception is shown, for the exact same procedure:

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]
Broken pipe or closed connection

rabbitmq:consumer [-m|--messages [MESSAGES]] [-r|--route [ROUTE]] [-l|--memory-limit [MEMORY-LIMIT]] [-d|--debug] [-w|--without-signals] [--] <name>

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException' with message 'Broken pipe or closed connection' in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(336): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
#1 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(457): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
#2 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(223): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame(1, Array, Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPWriter))
#3 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(170): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame(Array, Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\A in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 190

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException' with message 'Broken pipe or closed connection' in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(336): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
#1 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(457): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
#2 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(223): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame(1, Array, Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPWriter))
#3 /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(170): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame(Array, Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\A in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 190
```

Starting the consumer again, has the same effect. A few messages are consumed and then it exits again.

In php.ini max_execution_time and max_input_time are a lot higher than the time it takes for the exception to occur.

And the Symfony config.yml looks like this:

```
# rabbitmq
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
  connections:
    default:
      host:     '192.168.99.100'
      port:     5672
      user:     'guest'
      password: 'guest'
      vhost:    '/'
      lazy:     false
      connection_timeout: 4
      read_write_timeout: 4

      # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
      keepalive: false

      # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
      heartbeat: 2
```

**What is going on? And how to stop it from exiting until all messages have been consumed?**

Comment: my current fix is using supervisord to restart the workers automatically. And it works, but is a very ugly hack... I really hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same issue just now

Try change:

```
      connection_timeout: 60
      read_write_timeout: 60

      # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
      keepalive: false

      # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
      heartbeat: 30
```

It works for me.

Here is the explanation about how to use this values:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html

Good luck.

Comment: you fixed my problem and will set as answer, but why did it fix it? I read the documentation, but to no avail. I had timeouts and heartbeat in the same ratio as your fix. Any idea why it needs these greater values?